# has-error and has-success not working

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have created an Angular reactive form and using `ngClass`, I add Bootstrap's `has-success` and `has-error` classes depending on whether a form field is valid or not

```
/*checks if data inthe field is valid or not*/
  isFieldValid(field: string) {
    let fieldValid:boolean = this.signupForm.get(field).valid && this.signupForm.get(field).touched;
    console.log("isFieldValid for "+field+" returning "+fieldValid);
    return fieldValid;
  }

  /*add css to this control depending on whether it is valid or not*/
  displayFieldCss(field: string) {
    console.log("in displayFieldCss for field "+field);
    let fieldValid:boolean = this.isFieldValid(field);
    return {
        'has-error': !fieldValid, // if fieldvalid returns false i.e. field is not valid then we want has-error css. So set it to true (opp. of fieldValid)
        'has-success': fieldValid //if fieldvalid returns true i.e. field is valid then we want has-success css. So set it to true (value of fieldValid)
        //'has-feedback': this.isFieldValid(field)
    }
```

HTML

```
  <label for="firstname" class="control-label required">First Name</label>
  <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('firstName')" required>
  <app-show-errors [control]="signupForm.controls.firstName"></app-show-errors>
```

On inspecting the element in the browser, I can see that the classes are being added.

Inspect element if the field is empty

```
<input _ngcontent-c7="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched has-error" formcontrolname="firstName" id="firstname" required="" ng-reflect-klass="form-control" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="firstName" type="text">
```

Inspect element if the field is empty

```
<input _ngcontent-c7="" class="form-control ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid has-success" formcontrolname="firstName" id="firstname" required="" ng-reflect-klass="form-control" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="firstName" type="text">
```

But I don't see that `input` text box being bordered in red color for `has-error` or green color for `has-success`. Isn't this the default behavior of Bootstrap or do I need to provide `css` for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in bootstrap4, has-error and has-succes were dropped. Use "is-valid" and "is-invalid" instead:

```
... 
return {
  'is-invalid': !fieldValid, // if fieldvalid returns false i.e. field is not valid then we want has-error css. So set it to true (opp. of fieldValid)
  'is-valid': fieldValid //if fieldvalid returns true i.e. field is valid then we want has-success css. So set it to true (value of fieldValid)
  //'has-feedback': this.isFieldValid(field)
}
...
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukcju4)